# Transit Qatar visa by Qatar airways

Tags: visas, qatar-airways, qatar

Me and my girlfriend, both we need a transit visa to enter Qatar and our passports are not eligible to do it on arrival.

Qatar airways offers a service to make it for free. Cool. But the problem is that we'll fly from different countries so we'll not have the same ticket and we need to apply for a visa separately. I think that our chances to get visa is greater applying together than if visa officers see that my girlfriend goes there along.

Could someone who has already applied for a visa through Qatar airways tell me if there is a way to link our applications together.

Comment: Don't worry about chances.  It's not like you're applying for a 6 month visit. Go ahead file for your transit visa on your own tickets separately. You have paid tickets with the airline and if it provides you transit visa application option then it wants all genuine transit passengers to take the transit. Don't overthink

Comment: I read in web that for Russians almost 100% of requests of transit visa is refused. We are Ukrainians, I found nothing about ukrainian passports but in practice usually immigration rules are similar for all ex Soviet Union countries. 
And for as, we want a stopover for some days, and in case of refusal we cannot wait in the airport for 3 days. 
Moreover, we can apply for a transit visa 30 days before departure, they take a decision during at least 7 days so in case of refusal for one of us we need to change 2 tickets with modification fees about 270 euros for each one + pretty new tarif.

Comment: That's the case with any visas anywhere in the world, there is always a chance for denial but you have to apply somewhere. I have no clue as to why would Qatar block Russians or Ex USSR from Transiting 100%, i have never heard about that. Applying through the airline which has your confirmed ticket is still the best way to go about it

Comment: I know that refusal is always possible, also it's possible to be denied entry even with visa. The question is to try to minimize the risks and possible expenses in case of refusal :)

Comment: Where have you read about those 100% refusals?

Comment: I read some travel forum, quite popular, here is a link http://forum.awd.ru/viewtopic.php?f=735&t=301021 but it's in russian

Comment: In fact it's not 100% but I think 3 people from 4 says that they were refused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you think your chance to get a visa together is higher than separately. Qatar seem to issue transit visas to virtually everyone who applies, assuming reasonably clean record. And once you get there, you'd understand why :)

Just make sure you apply early in advance - [there's a 7 day processing time](https://transitvisa.qatarairways.com/transitvisa/online/qrvisa/applyVisa/search). And if you plan to spend there more than a day, have a clear idea of what you're going to do. You can see pretty much everything in touristy Doha in less than three hours.

Also Qatar Airlines used to allow you to change your itinerary for free if you're refused a visa. Considering that transit visa is also free, it is a no-brainer.

Update: [today Qatar related visa rules for Ukrainians](https://www.visitqatar.qa/plan/visas-requirements.html), allowing you to "apply" right at the airport. The "application" there consists of giving the immigration officer your passport and a credit card; that's all.

Comment: Wow, no more visa proir to arrival, cool. So we don't need to apply for it before arrival at all. Thanks for this info!

Comment: As for a question why I think that together we had more chances. Gulf countries don't like when young girls from eastern Europe travel along. I don't know the situation now, but several years ago women from east European countries younger than 30 could not ask for transit visa after arrival to UAE.

Comment: Understood. But unless you're legally married to her, or is her family member, I don't see how this would make significant difference.

Comment: UAE didn't like girls travelling alone. I suppose that in Qatar they have similar opinion. Thanks a lot for an info about obtention of visa on arrival from yesterday for ukrainian passports. Very good news :)